# C++ Handling uncaught exceptions

Tags: c++, exception

Hi all I'm facing some difficulties understanding the following code which deals with handling uncaught exceptions and I have a few question regarding the example below.

1) Just wondering why the output is: "call to my unexpected" and "caught bad expression" and not "call to my unexpected", "Caught X"

2) what does `throw(X,Y, bad_exception)` mean in 'void f()' function.

3) what does `typedef void (*pfv)();` actually means

```
class X { };
class Y { };
class A { };

typedef void (*pfv)();

void my_terminate() {
  cout << "Call to my_terminate" << endl;
  abort();
}

void my_unexpected() {
  cout << "Call to my_unexpected" << endl;
  throw;
}

void f() throw(X,Y, bad_exception) {
  throw A();
}

void g() throw(X,Y) {
  throw A();
}
int main()
{
  pfv old_term = set_terminate(my_terminate);
  pfv old_unex = set_unexpected(my_unexpected);
  try {
    cout << "In first try block" << endl;
    f();
  }
  catch(X) {
    cout << "Caught X" << endl;
  }
  catch(Y) {
    cout << "Caught Y" << endl;
  }
  catch (bad_exception& e1) {
    cout << "Caught bad_exception" << endl;
  }
  catch (...) {
    cout << "Caught some exception" << endl;
  }
 }
```

sorry for the multiple question being asked, hope someone is able to explain to me in layman terms. Thanks and appreciate..

Comment: Nah! Don't use throw specs. That's mostly considered deprecated for setting up APIs.

Comment: @g-makulik i didn't know that it's not wise to use throw spec, but i'm super new to c++ so just wondering why they would be the following output.

Comment: Have a look at Stuart's answer. That makes it pretty clear, why using throw specs (besides `nothrow`) makes it unnecessarily complicated to provide good class interfaces. Anything beyond to guarantee **'not to throw any exception'**, complicates maintenance to a jungle peppered with unpredictable pitfalls all along.

Comment: This is a relevant link about why exception specifications are something to avoid: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm

Comment: @StuartGolodetz ok great, think i got an idea now.. thanks guys!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) When you call `f`, it throws an exception whose type (`A`) is not part of its exception specification. This leads to the registered unexpected handler being called, which in this case is `my_unexpected`. This prints "Call to my_unexpected" and then rethrows the original exception (which as noted had a type that was not part of `f`'s exception specification), which causes a `bad_exception` to be thrown (but only because `bad_exception` is part of the exception specification of `f`). This is then caught in `main`, and "Caught bad_exception" is printed.

2) It means "`f` may throw an `X`, a `Y` or a `bad_exception`, and if it tries to throw anything else then the unexpected handler will be called".

3) It means "pfv is the type of a pointer to a function taking no parameters and with void return type". Thus `pfv old_term;` means that `old_term` is such a function pointer.

---

This is a useful link, for what it's worth:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr162.htm

The particularly relevant bit is at the bottom, where it says (emphasis mine):

> If unexpected() did not throw (or rethrow) an object allowed by the
>   exception specification of f(), then the C++ run time does one of two
>   things:
>
> - **If the exception specification of f() included the class std::bad_exception, unexpected() will throw an object of type
>     std::bad_exception, and the C++ run time will search for another
>     handler at the call of f().**
> - If the exception specification of f() did not include the class std::bad_exception, the function terminate() is called.